# When does Quicksort go from O(n log n) to O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, big-o-notation

Quicksort is O(n log n) average case, and O(n^2) worst case. The worst case occurs if one side of the pivot contains all of the elements and the other side contains none. However, I think the worst case would also occur if there is only one element on one side of the pivot each time and the rest on the other side. Is there a point, i.e. a factor of how unbalanced one side is compared to the other, where Quicksort goes from O(n^2) to O(n log n)?

Comment: What if there are 42 to one side for all *n* > 42? $\log(n), \sqrt(n), n/7$?

Comment: The answer depends on implementation details such as the pivot selection strategy.

Comment: You might want to check out Dan Spielman's results on smoothed complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I think the worst case would also occur if there is only one element on one side of the pivot each time and the rest on the other side.

Yes, however..

> Is there a point, i.e. a factor of how unbalanced one side is compared to the other

When expressed as a factor, the point where it becomes quadratic is "only when completely unbalanced". Even if the partitions are 0.1% vs 99.9%, quicksort is still in $O(n \log n)$-land. What changes is how big $n$ needs to be before the scaling starts to look noticeably less than quadratic, but that point will come for some sufficiently large $n$, so in terms of big O nothing changes. Such cases can still be considered pathological in practice.

Recall the Akra-Bazzi method. Given some recursive definition of $T(x)$ of this form (with some restrictions that I won't repeat here):

$$T(x) = g(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_iT(b_i x + h_i(x)) $$

So $g(x) = x$, $k = 2$, $a_i = 1$, and $b_1$ and $b_2$ represent the "split" between the two sides of the partition. Let's ignore $h_i$ this time.

The Akra–Bazzi method ask us to find a $p$ such that
$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_ib_i^p = 1 $, and since the b's add up to 1, $p = 1$.

Aside from $p$, the solution given by Akra-Bazzi does not depend on the specific values that the b's have. They're not in the formula:

$$T(x) \in \Theta(x^p (1 + \int_1^x \frac{g(u)}{u^{p+1}}du)) $$

The solution here is always $T(x) \in \Theta(x \log x)$, unless one of the b's is 0 and the other is 1. Staring at this formula it is not obvious why it would break, but Akra-Bazzi requires the b's to be strictly between 0 and 1, excluding those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise answer to this question. For a given $n$, the running time of Quicksort follows a statistical distribution with nonzero probabilities in $[\Theta(n\log n),\Theta(n^2)]$, but the exact distribution depends on the distribution of the input.

In the case of equiprobable permutations of the input numbers, the distribution remains concentrated around $\Theta(n\log n)$, and in the case of nearly sorted sequences, more around $\Theta(n^2)$, with a larger spread. But you could design distributions that result in intermediate expected complexities such as $\Theta(n^{3/2})$, if you wanted.

Last remarks: if you stick to input distributions such that all partitions are unevenly balanced but with a constant *ratio*, then the behavior is still $\Theta(n\log n)$, with an asymptotic constant that grows for ratios moving away from $\frac12$. For higher complexities, the partitions must get more imbalanced than proportionally.